# Create a lookup field on User object to Account Object

Tags: account, user, relationships, related-list, lookup-field

I want to have a related list 'Partnership Managers' on the Account object. All the partnership managers comes from the User object. For example, one account can have multiple partnership managers (users). When I try to create a lookup field on the User object, I don't see any such option. Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Will a User only be a Partnership Manager for one account? You might want to consider a junction object here that would allow a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: a junction object is a good option. yes, a user can be a partnership manager to many accounts.

Answer (score 3):

User object can only have Hierarchical relationships. There are a couple of ideas you can vote [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000fzF9AAI) and [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007WKpAAM). You can create a junction object between a user and account if that suits the requirement as mentioned in the comment above. That way a user can be related to multiple accounts.

Have you thought about using [Account teams](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/projects/protect-your-data-in-salesforce/set-up-account-teams)?

Do note that there will be impact on reporting and your apex code will need to be architected accordingly.

Comment: Good mention about Account Teams! I'd forgotten about this, and IMO you should implement this instead of creating custom functionality to do similar, Account Teams will have extra benefits like sharing...